# How can I restate this nonlinear function as a set of linear constraints?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraint-programming

I've been stuck with this problem for hours, so I'd be really grateful if anyone could give me a hand. I need to turn the following nonlinear function into a set of linear constraints:

Y3 = 0, IF Y1=0 and Y2=0 OR Y1=1 and Y2=1;

Y3 = 1, IF Y1=0 and Y2=1 OR Y1=1 and Y2=0

Where Y3 is a binary variable with values 0 or 1.

I have just taken a mathematical programming module so I'm not even sure what I'm asking for is even possible, but any opinions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't Y3 simply Y1 XOR Y2, given your definition?

Comment: I don't think so. Basically, Y3 needs to be 1 when Y1+Y2=1 and 0 when they equal 0 or 2.

Comment: @AlexE22 That is precisely what "XOR" means.

Comment: Let $z$ be a binary variable and use the constraint $$y_3 = y_1 + y_2 - 2z. $$

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much Math1000!!!!!! I kept asking the wrong question, now that I searched "XOR constraints" in the forum I instantly found what I needed. Thank you so, so much and sorry for the bother!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized all I needed to do was to apply the XOR constraints:

Y3<=Y1+Y2
Y3>=Y1-Y2
Y3>=Y2-Y1
Y3<=2-Y1-Y2
0<=Y3<=1

Many thanks to Math1000 and to Willie for pointing me in the right direction!